# flex chart annotationElement incorrect data points

Tags: apache-flex, annotations, charts

I have 2 Y-axis on the chart and I am trying to use annotationElement's localToData to get the data points associated with a Point on the chart.

The annotation Element is able to return a set of values for the point ( 1 Y - data, 1 -x data), But it is returning the values against one axis and not the other.

**Is there a way to associate the annotation element with a specific axis ?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry, this is more of a Flex issue which I did not fully understand at the time of posting.
At that time, My plot series was associated with right axis and hence I felt there was coding error on my end when i called localToData.

Anyway, there is a bug in Flex PlotSeries localToData method that shows up only if you have flex debugger installed.

The bug is a Null Pointer exception on Plot Series code while trying to get filtered data.